# printf gives unexpected result

Tags: c

I was wondering why the outcome of this program is 5621?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i=56;
    printf("%d\n",printf("%d",printf("%d",i)));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Does it even compile? `main` has no return type

Comment: Read about [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and what it returns, and learn about stacks, and you will understand.

Comment: printf : On success, returns the total number of characters written.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Most technical but short description :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes it does. C functions default to a return type of `int`.

Comment: A fun thing to do would be do this recursively. You might like to try learning about recursive functions if you want to extend your abilities. If you don't get anywhere with that, drop me a message and I will help you. (Or reply here with @Edward Bird)

Comment: @JAB Pre C99. The "implicit int" rule was abolished.

Comment: @DanielFischer true enough.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`printf` returns the amount of characters it has printed.

So first the most inner `printf` gets called with 56, printing `56`. Then it returns the amount of characters it has printed (2) to the middle `printf`, printing `2`. Then finally the amount of characters printed (1) gets passed into the outer `printf`, which then gets printed to procude `5621`.

Answer (score 9):

From the `printf` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

> Return value
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>   strings).

`56` is printed for the inner `printf`

2 characters were printed so the argument to the next `%d` format specifier is `2`

1 character was printed by the middle `printf` so the argument to the outer `%d` format specifier is `1`

Only the outer `printf` includes a newline so the preceding calls output one after another on the same line, giving `5621\n`.

Answer (score 6):

`printf()` returns the number of characters printed:

`printf("%d",i)` outputs the value `56`.
`printf("%d",printf("%d",i))` outputs `56` and then `2`, the number of characters in `56`.
`printf("%d\n",printf("%d",printf("%d",i)))` outputs `56`, then `2`, then the number of characters in `2`, which is `1`.

Answer (score 6):

It's equivalent to

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n, i = 56;
    n = printf("%d",i);
    n = printf("%d", n);
    n = printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

printf returns the number of characters written.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf()` function returns the number of characters that it prints on console.

For example after the following printf call, `num_chars` will have the value `10` as string `"Hi haccks\n"`   consistes of 10 non-nul characters that will be print on screen.

```
num_chars = printf("Hi haccks\n");
//                  ^^^^^^^^^ ^ 
//                  12345678910
```

**Note**: `\n` is single 10<sup>th</sup> char. So in above code returned value from printf assigned to `num_chars` variable.

In your code, in the given statement, inner `printf()` prints the values and then return number of chars that value printed by outer printf  as shown below:

```
// 1              2            3
printf("%d\n", printf("%d", printf("%d",i))); // Here i = 56
         ^              ^            ^    
   print: 1       print: 2         print: 56 
   returns: 1     returns: 1       returns: 2
//    3             2               1        <--Order of printf called
```

So it outputs 5621